# JQuery get data from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to add JQgrid to my project, but when I put the url with a method it doesn't return any data!

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#JQueryDemo").jqGrid({
            url: 'JqGrid.aspx/GetStudent',
           
            datatype: "JSON",
            colName: ['ID', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Mark'],
            colModel: [
             { name: 'id', index: 'id', stype: 'int', width: 200 },
            { name: 'firstName', index: 'firstname', width: 200 },
            { name: 'lastName', index: 'lastname', width: 200 },
            { name: 'gender', index: 'gender', width: 200 },
            { name: 'age', index: 'age', width: 200 },
            { name: 'mark', index: 'mark', width: 200 }],
            rowNum: 10,
            sortname: 'id',
            viewrecords: true,
            // sortorder: "desc",
            GridView: true,
            caption: "List Students Detail"
        });
```

How can I make it return data ?

I am working with asp.net and using n-tier style!

Comment: GridVeiw ----> GridView will be propably better

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I know this way but i need it in JQGrid @Vanojx1